# How to change DPI?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution, sip

I had monitor with scaling settings. They change DPI: (on LG Z27, 4K, via USB-C)

[image: macos dpi]

Now I have monitor with resolution settings. They change resolution and make picture worse: (on Aorus FI27Q, 2K, via HDMI)

[image: macos resolution]

Can I make my interface elements bigger without struggling with HiDPI? For HiDPI I need to disable SIP and I have no rights on my current MacBook.

Comment: You say you have no rights - is it not your machine? Perhaps ask the admin user.

Answer (score 2):

HiDPI options are normally only seen on HiDPI monitors. Are you sure that your Aorus monitor is a HiDPI display? From what I can find on the internet, it's a 2560 x 1440 27 inch display.

That said, the resolution options are a bit strange: there is no 2560 x 1440 option for example.

You can sometimes get more resolution options by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> (option) when clicking on the `Scaled` radio box.

Comment: Thank you for answers! Yes, my monitor is not HiDPI. But on Windows I can change DPI to make general size of elements bigger. And on macOS I need HiDPI, don't I? I mean, it's possible to change resolution and make picture worse.

Comment: @zored No, you don't need HiDPI. I have an Apple Thunderbolt Display, which is 2560 x 1440 px, no Retina. Have you tried holding down ALT like I mentioned?

Comment: thanks! Yes, I tried, but I have two 1080 options that make everything look blurry: https://imgur.com/DnwYLkU

Comment: Use the 2560 resolution. That's the display's native size. Don't use the 1080 sizes.